# Get folder path/directory in react js using 'window.showDirectoryPicker'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using Window.showDirectoryPicker for saving a file in particular directory.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/showDirectoryPicker

I want to show the selected directory/path beside the 'Select path' button. Is that possible to get the path on selecting the folder.

```
function getNewFileHandle() {
  const opts = {
    types: [{
      description: 'Text file',
      accept: {'text/plain': ['.txt']},
    }],
  };

  return window.showDirectoryPicker(opts);
}

 return(
 <Button onClick={getNewFileHandle}>Select path</Button>
 )
```